# uncaught (in promise) typeerror: cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

I was following a "The Coding Train" video on how to code minesweeper in js

It was for my school project, but I had one problem, first I am a new programmer

I was following then I got the "uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0') on line 22, column 24

My code is:

```
var grid;
var cols;
var rows;
var w = 20;

function make2DArray(cols, rows) {
    var arr = new Array(cols);
    arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[1] = new Array(rows);
        }
        return arr;
    }
    
function setup() {
    createCanvas(200, 200);
    cols = floor(width / w);
    rows = floor(height / w);
    grid = make2DArray(cols, rows);
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) { 
            grid[i][j] = new Cell(i * w, j * w, w);
        }
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            grid[i][j].show();
}
    }
}
```

I tried adding "for (var j = 0; j < arr.width; j++) under the integer variable in "make2DArray" and expecting it to work just like how the tutorial did

Comment: wrong `var arr = new Array(cols); arr = [];` and  this is wrong`arr[1] = new Array(rows);`

Comment: `arr = [];` sets `arr` to be an empty array with length 0, undoing the previous code

Answer (score -1):

The issue is actually in `make2DArray`. Comments inline:

```
function make2DArray(cols, rows) {
  var arr = new Array(cols);
  // ⚠️ The below replaces the array created on line 7, making the new length 0
  arr = [];  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // ⚠️ and here you're always setting the 1st element to a new array. You want to use `i` here so you are creating a new col array for each row
    arr[1] = new Array(rows);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

It looks like you're making a grid with columns of rows (ie `cell = grid[col][row]`). I recommend making your grid with rows of columns, as that's more common way of thinking about 2D data.
Whichever you use, be careful to keep using the access pattern consistently.